# Can't use NumericProperty in pos() of a widget

Tags: python, kivy

**[SOLVED]**

I am trying to use a NumericProperty inside the kivy lang. I can't figure out how to use it inside of a pos argument

When I run the code I get the following error:
**"kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.****getattr**

I want to insert a value into the pos of a widget via a NumericProperty. How do I do that?

**This code has been simplified**
main.py

```
class Game(Screen):
    def SomeFunction(self):
        self.value = 60
   
        X = NumericProperty(self.value)
```

main.kv

```
Game:
    FloatLayout:
        SomeWidget:
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5}
            pos: (root.X, 50)
```

I expected the Widget to move by the amount given by X*(the NumericProperty)*, tho the aforementioned
error occurred.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Kivy properties are supposed to be defined at [class level](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-using-bind).

Comment: OK, I changed my code and it seems to work! Thanks :)